fork() creates a different type of child process in minix2
I am trying to implement a group priority scheduler in minix2, and I ran into some problems. I have a test-script:
#include <lib.h>
#include <minix/callnr.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    message m;
    int grp = 2;
    int add_prior = 2;
    time_t exec_time = 10;
    int counter = 1;
    pid_t main_pr = getpid();

    printf("mainPID: %d\n", getpid());

    for(counter; counter <= 30; counter++) {
        if(grp % 4 == 0) {
            grp++;
        }
        m.M1_i1 = (grp % 4);
        if(add_prior > 24) {
            add_prior = 2;
        }
        m.M1_i2 = (grp % 4) * 25 - add_prior;
        m.M1_i3 = exec_time;
        if(getpid() == main_pr) {
            m.M2_l1 = fork();
            if(m.M2_l1 > 0) {
                _syscall(MM, DO_SETPRI, &m);
            }
        }
        add_prior++;
        exec_time++;
        grp++;
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

and the screenshot(all the screenshots duplicate the text code but are the original code source, I added them due to not being able to access the files from the code in the virtual machine, so the text code was scanned from the screenshots): 
All it does is create multiple processes and custom parameters for them. For each process, it executes a system call that sets custom fields.
And syscall:
PRIVATE int do_setprio(m_ptr)
register message *m_ptr;
{
    struct proc *child_proc;

    // printf(" M2_l1:%d M1_i1:%d\n", m_ptr->M2_l1, m_ptr->M1_i1);
    child_proc = proc_addr(m_ptr->M2_l1);

    if (isuserp(child_proc)) { printf("\n user \n"); }
    if (istaskp(child_proc)) { printf("\n task \n"); }
    if (isservp(child_proc)) { printf("\n serv \n"); }

    child_proc->pr_grp = m_ptr->M1_i1;
    child_proc->pr_priority= m_ptr->M1_i2;
    child_proc->pr_exec_time= m_ptr->M1_i3;

    printf("Data of created process: PID:%d GRP:%d PRIOR:%d \n", m_ptr->M2_l1, child_proc->pr_grp, child_proc->pr_priority);
    return 0;
}

and the screenshot:
So when I started testing, I noticed that the created processes behaved strangely (they end before they should; I added a part of the code that should be executed by the child processes). I decided to check if they get into sched(), and it turned out that none of them go there. After that, I decided to check what type they are, and added these outputs in the system call:
if (isuserp(child_proc)) { printf("\n user \n"); }
if (istaskp(child_proc)) { printf("\n task \n"); }
if (isservp(child_proc)) { printf("\n serv \n"); }

and got a very interesting output (screenshot):
As you can see, some processes from the same parent can be both user and system types, others do not have a type at all or are idle, and in addition, the kernel began to panic (which did not happen before these logs). I tried to fix it by myself, but for a long time I could not figure out what the problem is and what is happening here, so I am asking for your help and advice.

Why do you add screenshots of your code? Is it the same code? Then the screenshot is useless. Is it different? Then do you expect us to spot the difference? At least whitespace is different. As we do not put your code into Photoshop, why would we want a picture of it? Please only provide the code as formatted text in your question. The same is valid for your output. Please edit the question to replace it with text. And remove the pictures.

@Gerhardh Cause i have minix on vm and it's impossible to get the original code files from it (at least I haven't found a way) to copy paste, so the text code was scanned from the screenshots. I checked them for sameness, but added screenshots of the original code just in case.

@Gerhardh I added an explanation about this to the text of the question, thanks
